# Scrapy crawling speed is slow

Tags: python, scrapy

I had been crawling a ecommerce website using Scrapy and the crawling speed I am getting is 50~60 pages/minute.
I am using 8 core linode server with 24 GB Ram, so I don't think network or server could be the reason.

I am aware of the fact the some websites give download latency if we crawl them too often, but this is a large website and I am using **proxymesh** proxies too, so this also could not be possibly the reason.

I think I am missing something in settings.py file -

```
BOT_NAME = 'scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['com.crawler.scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'com.crawler.scraper.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'com.crawler.scraper.pipelines.generic_pipeline.Pipeline': 300
}
RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = False
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
CONCURRENT_ITEMS = 200
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=50
DOWNLOAD_DELAY= 0
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN=50
LOG_LEVEL = 'ERROR'
RETRY_TIMES = 2
CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30
USER_AGENT_LIST = 'user_agents.txt'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'random_useragent.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'com.crawler.scraper.middlewares.proxy_middleware.ProxyMiddleware': 410,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
}
```

I started from **DOWNLOAD_DELAY 5** and now even I have kept it as 0 but still I couldn't see any significant change in the number of requests per minute.

So, my questions are ->

1) What should I do to increase the speed to at least 200 requests/minute?
2) What should be the ideal value for CONCURRENT_ITEMS?

Comment: What is the average response time for a single page? 50-60rpm is already significant load for a single client.

Comment: But if I am using dynamic proxies, the website couldn't identify that the requests are coming from the same client, and the website is amazon, and I had seen others crawling at a much higher speed, @jordanm

Comment: Is the [AutoThrottle extension](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html) on or off? You can disable it and check if it makes any difference.

Comment: @paultrmbrth I think it is disabled by default

Comment: If you created your project with `scrapy startproject`, the `settings.py` contains `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED=True`. You can check that in the logs when the crawl starts, where the middlewares are listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CONCURRENT_ITEMS is definitely not the solution as this setting has only impact on the processing time used on the server and given your server specs that shouldn't make a difference at all.

Besides that your settings look ok, your scraper should go as fast as the site responds. (even when upping DOWNLOAD_DELAY to 1, the scraper would have the potential to do 50 x 60 = 3000 requests a minute)

Oh and RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY should also be set to True, just to be sure.

**Depending on the number of proxies you use, it is very likely that the target site is throttling your scraper.**

At the current speed, if using ProxyMesh's smallest 20 IP plan, you would be hitting the site every 20 seconds from the same IP. If using their 100 IP plan you'd be still sending a request from each IP every 100-120 seconds.

Doing this over an extended period of time is fast enough to get your ProxyMesh IPs throttled. Also I would speculate your scraper was faster when starting out and then got throttled because of this.

Ways to check my theory: either add more IPs and the speed should increase accordingly or wait 24 hours until ProxyMesh assigned you new IPs and then run the scraper again and watch if it starts much faster and then gets throttled down.

Comment: just to clarify the things more, I am using proxymesh world proxy, which gives a very large amount of IP's(not sure of the number).

Comment: As far as I understand the price structure of proxymesh, they limit your number of IPs per day and rotate them out after 24 hours. So only a fraction of the full 15k IPs of the proxymesh world proxy will be available to you on a single day (unless you have signed up for some unofficial plan they don't list on their site)